# How to disable a JavaScript, with inner window width

Tags: javascript

The page I am working on has a tilt effect, which affects the orientation of the site body. I want to turn this off when the page reaches a mobile viewport; I have looked and tried a few thing but can't seem to get the effect I want. The code below is what i am using. This script runs separate from my main JS code.

```
window.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e) {

  var width = window.innerWidth;
  var height = window.innerHeight;
  var clientHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
  var skew = {};
  skew.y = (20 * ((e.x / width) - 0.5));
  skew.x = -(20 * ((e.y / height) - 0.5));

  document.body.style.webkitTransform = "perspective("+clientHeight+"px) rotateX("+skew.x+"deg) rotateY("+skew.y+"deg)";

});
```

Comment: What do you mean "turn this off"? As in, simply don't run that script if the user's device's screen is below some specific size? Or turn it off and on dynamically in response to the user resizing the browser window?

Comment: I would like the tilt to only come on when the broswer window is full size.. I have tried the following.                          window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    if(window.innerWidth > 568){
        ...execute script
    } But it does not seem to work, I guess i don't know the syntax for the script to run?

Answer (score 0):

CSS changes won't remove themselves, so you'll have to remove the transform manually if the browser window is under your desired size.

Check on window resize,

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  if (window.innerWidth < 568) {
    document.body.style.webkitTransform = '';
  }
});
```

And also make sure not to reapply it if the user moves their mouse.

```
// This is the function you already have
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (window.innerWidth < 568) {
    return;
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: So would i add these to the JS file that is responsible for the effect, or into the main JS file for the site?

Comment: The JS file responsible for the effect. The second piece of code is a modification to what you posted originally, just add that if statement inside the mousemove function.

Comment: Okay i think i got it working for the most part, it's still doing a little twist when in mobile, but it's better then it was.. Thanks alot for the help.

Comment: If it still initially has twist, try running document.body.style.webkitTransform = ''; when the page loads.

If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as "accepted" by hitting the big check mark.